# Using JOIN FETCH in sublevels having one to many relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hql, jpql

I'm using Spring Data JPA in my application. DB2 is the DB and the table designs are legacy which cannot be changed.

I have below classes. *Account* class one to many relationship with *Job* and Job has One to Many relationship with *Task*.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AccountId id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_type", referencedColumnName = "ACCOUNT_TYPE")
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_number", referencedColumnName = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_code", referencedColumnName = "LOCATION_CODE")
    private List<Job> jobs;

    // More fields...
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT_JOB")
public class Job {

    @EmbeddedId
    private JobId id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_number", referencedColumnName = "JOB_NUMBER")
    @JoinColumn(name = "part_number", referencedColumnName = "PART_NUMBER")
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_date", referencedColumnName = "JOB_DATE")
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_type", referencedColumnName = "ACCOUNT_TYPE")
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_number", referencedColumnName = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_code", referencedColumnName = "LOCATION_CODE")
    private List<Task> tasks;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOB_TASK")
public class Task {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TaskId id;
    
    @Column(name = "AP_PAY_CODE")
    private String taskName;
    
    @Column(name = "TASK_STATUS_DATE")
    private Date taskStatusDate;
}
```

I want to fetch and Account and all it's Job and associated Tasks. If I mention fetch type EAGER in the relationships, I'm able to get whole data by passing Account Id using the *findById* method in Repository.
But for many scenarios I want to get Account only and others needs to be lazy loaded when necessary.

So I thought of having custom query to use `JOIN FETCH` to get all data together instead of findById. But how to write query to JOIN FETCH to join at sublevels?

```
@Query("SELECT account FROM Account account JOIN FETCH account.jobs jobs /*WHAT TO ADD HERE*/ where account.id = :accountId")
Optional<Account> getAccountData(@Param("accountId") AccountId accountId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this native query to fetch each job and their respective tasks

```
 @Query(value="select a.jobs,b.tasks from ACCOUNT a join ACCOUNT_JOB b on 
ACCOUNT_TYPE  a.account_type=b.ACCOUNT_TYPE  join JOB_TASK C on 
b.ACCOUNT_TYPE=c.id",nativeQuery=true)
```

Comment: Only native query is possible is it?

Comment: yeah it is also easier you can cross chcek from database also

Comment: does this solve your issue?

Comment: I have not tried. This means I have to put all fields in the query and then get as `List<Object[]>` and map each fields separately. Sometimes if the list size is huge, it would take more time to process. I'm looking for hibernate way

Comment: It will take some time to fetch record but it will surely helps you to get desired result                                                                                                                                           
           try this if it helps please accept my answer